# Stringly typed values table in sql, is there a better way to do this? (we're using MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server

We have have a table layout with property names in one table, and values in a second table, and items in a third. (Yes, we're re-implementing tables in SQL.)

We join all three to get a value of a property for a specific item.

Unfortunately the values can have multiple data types double, varchar, bit, etc. Currently the consensus is to stringly type all the values and store the type name in the column next to the value.

tblValues
DataTypeName nvarchar

Is there a better, cleaner way to do this?

**Clarifications:**

Our requirements state that we must add new "attributes" at run time without modifying the db schema

I would prefer not to use EAV, but that is the direction we are headed right now.

This system currently exists in SQL server using a traditional db design, but I can't see a way to fulfill our requirement of not modifying the db schema without moving to EAV.

Comment: Yes. Use SQL server the way it was intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are really only two patterns for implementing an 'EAV model' (assuming that's what you want to do):

1. Implement it as you've described, where you explicitly store the property value type along with the value, and use that to convert the string values stored into the appropriate 'native' types in the application(s) that access the DB.
2. Add a separate column for each possible datatype you might store as a property value. You could also include a column that indicates the property value type, but it wouldn't be strictly necessary.

Solution 1 is a simpler design, but it incurs the overhead of converting the string values stored in the table into the appropriate data type as needed.

Solution 2 has the benefit of storing values as the appropriate native type, but it will necessarily require more, though not necessarily much more, space. This may be moot if there aren't a lot of rows in this table. You may want to add a check constraint that only allows one non-NULL value in the different value columns, or if you're including a type column (so as to avoid checking for non-NULL values in the different value columns), prevent mismatches between the value stored in the type column and which value column contains the non-NULL value.

As HLGEM states in her answer, this is less preferred than a standard relational design, but I'm more sympathetic to the use of EAV model table designs for data such as application option settings.

Answer (score 3):

Well don't do that! You lose all the values of having datatypes if you do. You can't properly constrain them (and will, I guarantee it, get bad data eventually) and you have to cast them back to the proper type to use in mathematical or date calculations. All in all a performance loser.

Your whole design will not scale well. Read up on why you don't want to use EAV tables in a relational database. It is not only generally slower  but unusually difficult to query especially for reporting.

Perhaps a noSQL database would better suit your needs or a proper relational design and NOT an EAV design. Is it really  too hard to figure out what fields each table would really need or are your developers just lazy? Are you sacrificing performance for flexibility - a flexibility that most users will hate? Especially when it means bad performance? Have you ever used a database designed that way to try to do anything?

Comment: While this answer is true enough in general, there are certain specific circumstances where an EAV model table design is warranted, such as application option settings.

Comment: Q1: Is it really too hard to figure out what fields each table would really need or are your developers just lazy? - No, and no, our requirements are that we have to be able to add new properties on the fly.

Q2:Are you sacrificing performance for flexibility[...]? This is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Q3:Have you ever used a database designed that way to try to do anything? Yes, which is why I am asking for help.

Comment: I urge you to look at noSQL databases for the flexible part. No reason why they can't be used in conjunction with SQL Server. Or consider if an XML field would work. Or even an nvarchar(max) if there is going to be no functionality associated with these added fields aside from showing the information.  SQL Server simply doesn't handle this sort of thing very well. At least define as many things as you can up front and don't rely on the EAV table to define everything. Trust me this stuff is not pretty to query!

Comment: >Trust me this stuff is not pretty to query: I know, and I appreciate your response. I am looking for alternatives but using SQL server is mandated in this situation.

Comment: well then at least use @Kenny Evitt's suggestion #2 so you aren't continually converting data types.